# Django display hyperlink only to the creator of the object

Tags: django

I'm working on an project that let users create blogs and allow other users to comment on each other blogs.When a user creates a blog , their are certain ability that the blog owner can do such as deleting their own comments and the way I'm deleting comments is via  hyperlink passing value id . 
Everyone can see each other blogs but I want to only show the deletion hyperlink to the owner of the blog , so only the user who created the blog. How can I do this? via template

My models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField()

def Bloglook(request ,animal_id):
        Blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=animal_id)
    return render(request,'blog.html',{blog':blog})
```

my blog.html

```
{% if blog %}
    {{blog.name%}}
{% endif %}
```

How Can I only show this link to the person who created the blog?

```
<a  href="{% url world:BlogDelete blog.id %}"> Delete blog</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to pass to template which passes `request.user` variable to template, which you can use to check for owner of blog.

Change your view to use `RequestContext` as

```
def Bloglook(request ,animal_id):
    Blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=animal_id)
    return render_to_response('blog.html',{blog':blog}, 
             context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Then in template do

```
{% if blog.owner == request.user %}
     <a  href="{% url world:BlogDelete blog.id %}"> Delete blog</a>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Rohan , what about the other people who are not authenicated?

Comment: This will also be hidden from unautenticated users. Only if user is the owner then he will see the deletion link

Comment: @Jacob, unauthenticated users will be anonymous users, which will not match with blog owners user.

Comment: I see what you mean , Thank you Rohan :D

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if request.user==blog.user %}<a  href="{% url world:BlogDelete blog.id %}"> Delete blog</a>{% endif %}
```

Edited:

This will also be hidden from unautenticated users. Only if user is the owner then he will see the deletion link

Also, you can continue using `render`, there is no need to change to `render_to_response.`

Comment: Thank you akshar raaj , I have to tick rohan answer because he answer it 1 min before you but I will give you a +1 :D

Comment: Make sure to add `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, so that you can access `request` in your template.